# USB 3.0 coping with slow speed on Ubuntu as opposed to Windows

Tags: usb

In my Toshiba E329786 USB 3.0 port, Ubuntu speeds are slower, like 3MBPS - 5MBPS, than in a different PC running Windows 7, like 100MBPS - 120MBPS.

How can I increase the speeds in Ubuntu??

Output of `lsusb`:

```
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0a81:0101 Chesen Electronics Corp. Keyboard
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 046d:c05a Logitech, Inc. Optical Mouse M90
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 0fce:7172 Sony Ericsson Mobile Communications AB
```

Comment: Can you post the output of `lsusb`?

Comment: Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

    Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

    Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub

    Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub

    Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0a81:0101 Chesen Electronics Corp. Keyboard

    Bus 001 Device 004: ID 046d:c05a Logitech, Inc. Optical Mouse M90

    Bus 002 Device 004: ID 0fce:7172 Sony Ericsson Mobile Communications AB

Comment: You don't seem to have a USB 3.0 port on your computer, or it is falsely recognized as USB 2.0 port.

Comment: Yes, there is no USB 3.0 port in my computer. But the PC that is running windows 7 is similar like mine.

Comment: Does your Windows 7 computer have USB 3.0?

Comment: No, my windows 7 computer doesn't have USB 3.0.

Answer (score 1):

According to the information provided by you, it's unlikely that this is an Ubuntu related issue. The transfer speed on your Ubuntu machine, while a bit low, lies within the USB 2.0 specification. The speed on your Windows machine exceeds the USB 2.0 specification, which is probably because your USB hub in that machine allows higher transfer rates than specified, as is the case for some newer 2.0 hubs.